# ArrayList of objects, compare objects and find duplicates, add object to new ArrayList only once for each duplicate

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates, compare

Ive figured out how to compare the two ArrayLists and add the duplicates to a new ArrayList.

```
    ArrayList<Student> allStudentsA = assignStudents();
    ArrayList<Student> allStudentsB = allStudentsA;

    for (Student studentA : allStudentsA) {
        for (Student studentB : allStudentsB) {
            if (studentA.getId().equals(studentB.getId()) && studentA.getEduNumber() != studentB.getEduNumber()) {
                duplicateStudents.add(studentB);
            }
        }
    }
```

However done the way i do it, i add each duplicate once for everytime its there. Since "Rodaba" is there 7 times as she has 7 different priorities, she gets added to the list 7*6 times. Heres how i print out:

```
    for (Student student : duplicateStudents) {
        if (student.getFornavn().equals("Rodaba")) {
            System.out.println("Name: " + student.getFornavn() + "\t \t" + "EduNumber: " + student.getOptagelsesområde() + "\t" + "Prio: " + student.getPrio());
        }
    }
```

Is there a clever way i can avoid this, and only add "Rodaba" once for each priority she has applied for?
Heres my output, is there a way to only get the marked section?
[image: Heres my output, is there a way to only get the marked section]

I've been stuck on this for a long time. I'd really appreciate both suggestions on a better way to make the ArrayLists, as well as how to figure out this problem.

Comment: I think using `Map` could be a good solution. Also it eliminates nested `for` loops as well.

Comment: Why not just check if the student is already in the list? Also, it has no connection with this but you could override your `Student#toString` method to print it more cleanly

Comment: @Nathan The problem with that is that the student will be in the list _n_ times where _n_ is the amount of priorities they have.

Comment: @RohitMourya Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @LarsChristensen Then, just check if it exists in the list with the same priority.

Comment: @Nathan thanks for the suggestion, i will try to make this work.

Comment: if you don't want to change the logic to a faster map (hell even a list.contains with correct equals) why don't you just add the Priority to your if condition before adding?

Comment: Use a set to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments, you can simply check for the presence of one student before adding it:

```
ArrayList<Student> allStudentsA = assignStudents();
ArrayList<Student> allStudentsB = allStudentsA;

for (Student studentA : allStudentsA)
    for (Student studentB : allStudentsB)
        if (studentA.getId().equals(studentB.getId())
            && studentA.getEduNumber() != studentB.getEduNumber())
            if (!duplicateStudents.contains(studentB))
                duplicateStudents.add(studentB);
```

Note that this will only work **if** you overrode the `equals` and `hashCode` method of your `Student` class, as the objects do not have the same references.

Basically, you will check if the `Student` is already in the list before adding it. If you implemented correctly your `equals` method, a student **A**  won't be equal to **A with a different priority** .

Comment: Again the problem with this is, that it stops adding when it runs into the first student. So it only adds "Rodaba" once, on the 25th priority, where as what i want is to add it once for every priority.

Comment: @LarsChristensen Then it falls back on your `Student#equals` implementation: it seems your equals method returns true even when the priorities are differents.

Comment: You are a god Nathan, thats where the problem was. I edited my equals method to check properly for priorities, and the problem was solved.

Comment: @LarsChristensen Glad I could help, but I can't accept the god part -- this honor falls back to [Jon Skeet, SO's Chuck Norris](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different approach with streams. Eg:

```
List<Student> allStudentsA = assignStudents();
List<Student> duplicateStudents = allStudents.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Student::getId)) 
//Now you've got Map<String, List<Student>> (assuming id is of type String).
//Id of an user is a key. In value (list) you have all Students with the same id.
//Now we want to take this lists which have size greater than two and merge them.
    .values()
    .stream()
    .filter(list -> list.size() >= 2)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(Improvements are welcome.)

Comment: Thank you for the alternative approach.